# For in-memory caching and operations which is better - Ignite or MemSQL

Tags: performance, ignite, in-memory, singlestore

For our project, we need to load huge amount of structured data on in-memory cache daily and need to perform some calculations on the data when a request is received. We need very low latency and high throughput for our use case. Can anybody provide a comparison between Ignite and MemSQL performance for such case?

Comment: FYIW here is a comparison of ignite vs hazelcast http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932836/hazelcast-vs-ignite-benchmark

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to provide generic comparison as it heavily depends on the use case, hardware, amounts of data, etc... You should create your own benchmark that will represent your case and run it on different products. This will give a good picture of which product is better for you.